# Convert the last generated .Coverage into coveragexml for SonarQubee in TFS 2017

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops, sonarqube, tfsbuild

I am using .Net Core Test `--collect  "Code coverage"` to generate a coverage file, I need to convert this for sonarqube, the issue is I do not nave the name of the file thats generated as its placed in a folder with a guid name and the file name itself is a GUID all under the `TestResults` folder

The following script works to convert `.coverage` files into `coveragexml`, but its for the whole working directory

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "*.coverage" | % {
$outfile = "$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.FullName)).coveragexml"
$output = [System.IO.Path]::Combine([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($_.FullName), $outfile)
"Analyse '$($_.Name)' with output '$outfile'..."
. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Team Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage Tools\codecoverage.exe" analyze /output:$output $_.FullName
}
```

But this converts the whole directory and after several days there are many builds, all I want to do it convert the `.coverage` file generated by the current build, so I need to be able to isolate the `.coverage` files generated by the current build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to take only the last created code coverage file, you can filter the `Get-ChiledItem` results to get the last one:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "*.coverage" | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1
```